# LSTM on top of a pre-trained CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have trained a CNN and now I want to load the model and then on top put a LSTM but I'm getting some errors.

```python
'''
Load the output of the CNN
'''
cnn_model = load_model(os.path.join('weights', 'CNN_patch_epoch-20.hdf5'))

last_layer = cnn_model.get_layer('pool5').output    

''' Freeze previous layers '''
for layer in cnn_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(last_layer)
x = LSTM(neurons, dropout=dropout, name='lstm')(x)
out = Dense(n_output, kernel_initializer=weight_init, name='out')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[cnn_model.input], outputs=out)

model.summary()
```

I'm not sure where to specify that I want 5 frames (images). So my input would be `(None, 5, 224, 224, 3)`. So my question is where should I specify it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your `cnn_model` also in a `TimeDistributed` wrapper.

```py
frames = Input(shape=(5, 224, 224, 3))
x = TimeDistributed(cnn_model)(frames)
x = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(x)
x = LSTM(neurons, dropout=dropout, name='lstm')(x)
out = Dense(n_output, kernel_initializer=weight_init, name='out')(x)
model = Model(inputs=frames, outputs=out)
```